# Convert a non-project directory within a project to a sub-project in MKS?

Tags: mks-integrity

I've got a project in MKS Integrity (not my choice...) that has numerous sub-directories, not sub-projects.  Is there an easy process or method or command to convert all sub-directories into sub-projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy, but could be involved, depending on your situation:

Suppose you are using Integrity 10.4, and in your sandbox you have a subdirectory named "alpha":

1. Select all the members in the "alpha" subfolder (I think this works in the sandbox, as well).
2. From the menu, choose **Member -> Move**.
3. Hit **Next >**.
4. In the "Move Members Wizard" dialog, note the "Source Sandbox Name" and "Destination Sandbox Name" are the same.
5. In the destination directory dialog options, add the subdirectory name "alpha" (the name of the current subfolder)
6. Set "Create Subprojects" option (hit **Options >>** to show the options).
7. Accept the changes by hitting **Finish**.

This should create a subproject with the same name as the subfolder.

**Disclosure:**  I work for PTC Integrity Support.

Comment: Just wanted to add that if applying this method Inegrity will politely generate a new revision of the moved member wich do not differ from the previous version but have the revision description:

"Member moved from alpha/src1.c in project ..../project.pj to src1.c in project ..../aplha/project.pj"

Comment: Thanks for the addition, grenix.  Sorry for the late acknowledgement.